# Error when trying to make a GeoDataFrame of network nodes

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, geopandas, osmnx

I need to make a GeoDataFrame of some nodes on a road network (which was extracted from OpenStreetMap using OSMnx). In the code below, `graph_proj` is the graph whose nodes I'm working with, the points are `start_point` and `end_point`:

```
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
nodes_proj, edges_proj = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph_proj, nodes=True, edges=True)

# Finding the nodes on the graph nearest to the points
start_node = ox.nearest_nodes(graph_proj, start_point.geometry.x, start_point.geometry.y, return_dist=False)
end_node = ox.nearest_nodes(graph_proj, end_point.geometry.x, end_point.geometry.y, return_dist=False)
start_closest = nodes_proj.loc[start_node]
end_closest = nodes_proj.loc[end_node]

# Create a GeoDataBase from the start and end nodes
od_nodes = gpd.GeoDataFrame([start_closest, end_closest], geometry='geometry', crs=nodes_proj.crs)
```

During the last step ("# Create a GeoDataBase...", etc.), an error is thrown. Apparently, it has something to do with a 3-dimensional array being passed to the GeoDataFrame function. Am I right that the way I pass in the locations(`[start_closest, end_closest]`) results in a 3D array? (The error message reads, 'Must pass 2-d input. shape=(2, 1, 7)') I tried transposing this array, but then GeoPandas could not locate the 'geometry' column. How do I go about passing in this argument in a way that it will be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I was able to get around this by writing each node to its own GeoDataFrame and then merging the two GeoDataFrames, like this:

```
od_nodes1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(start_closest, geometry='geometry', crs=nodes_proj.crs)
od_nodes2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(end_closest, geometry='geometry', crs=nodes_proj.crs)
od_nodes = od_nodes1.append(od_nodes2)
```

Surely, though, there must be a more elegant way of writing more than one feature into a GeoDataFrame?